# A non abelian group of order 12 as a Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

Does there exist a polynomial over the rational Field $\mathbb Q$ whose Galois group is a non abelian group of order 12?

If we consider the cyclotomic polynomial containing the primitive 13th roots of unity, its Galois group turns out to be the cyclic group of order 12. But the question wants me to find a polynomial for which we get a non abelian group of order 12 as its Galois group, if it exists. Is it possible? Please give one example. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you find a polynomial whose Galois group is $S_{3}$ (which is nonabelian of order 6)? Does that help you to form a polynomial with the group you want?

Comment: X^3 -2 for example gives a Galois group of order 6.

Comment: The group $A_n$ is the Galois group of a number field, in particular $A_4$ which has order $12$.